# AngularJS + ASP.NET $http.post returning 401

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, post

I am trying to add a new Stop to my database. But I get  a 401 error in asp.net.

.js file:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("app-trips")
        .controller("tripEditorController", tripEditorController);
    function tripEditorController($routeParams, $http) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.tripName = $routeParams.tripName;
        vm.stops = [];
        vm.newStop = {};

        vm.addStop = function () {
            alert(vm.newStop.name);
            $http.post("/api/trips/" + vm.tripName + "/stops", vm.newStop)
                .then(function (response) {
                    vm.stops.push(vm.newStop);
                };
       }
}
```

.html file (input form):

```
<form novalidate name="newStopForm" ng-submit="vm.addStop()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Date</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="arrival" name="arrival" ng-model="vm.newStop.arrival" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Location</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" ng-model="vm.newStop.name" required ng-minlength="3" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="newStopForm.$invalid" />
    </div>
</form>
```

C# Post code:

```
 [HttpPost("/api/trips/{tripName}/stops")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post(string tripName, [FromBody]StopViewModel vm)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var newStop = Mapper.Map<Stop>(vm);
                    var result =await _coordsService.GetCoordsAsync(newStop.Name);
                    if (!result.Succes)
                    {
                        _logger.LogError(result.Message);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newStop.Latitude = result.Latitude;
                        newStop.Longitude = result.Longitude;
                    }
                    _repository.AddStop(tripName, newStop, User.Identity.Name);
                    if (await _repository.SaveChangesAsync())
                    {
                        return Created($"/api/trips/{tripName}/stops/{newStop.Name}",
                                         Mapper.Map<StopViewModel>(newStop));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Failed to save new Stop: {0}", ex);
            }
            return BadRequest("Failed to save new stop");
        }
```

GeoCoordsService.cs:

```
public async Task<GeoCoordsResult> GetCoordsAsync(string name)
{
    var result = new GeoCoordsResult()
    {
        Succes = false,
        Message = "Failed to get coordinates"
    };
    var apiKey = _config["Keys:BingKey"];
    var encodedName = WebUtility.UrlEncode(name);
    var url = $"http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?q={encodedName}&key={apiKey}";

    var client = new HttpClient();
    var json = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

    var results = JObject.Parse(json);
    var resources = results["resourceSets"][0]["resources"];
    if (!resources.HasValues)
    {
        result.Message = $"Could not find '{name}' as a location";
    }
    else
    {
        var confidence = (string)resources[0]["confidence"];
        if (confidence != "High")
        {
            result.Message = $"Could not find a confident match for '{name}' as a location";
        }
        else
        {
            var coords = resources[0]["geocodePoints"][0]["coordinates"];
            result.Latitude = (double)coords[0];
            result.Longitude = (double)coords[1];
            result.Succes = true;
            result.Message = "Success";
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I have read, that this is probably caused because the data is not in the right format, does anyone know what would be the right format, my webpage returns error 400, but deeper in my C# I can see that function `var json = await client.GetStringAsync(url);`is returning an error 401 (Unotharized). I guess I should also add username somewhere, but I don't know where.

Comment: It might be helpful to post the asp.net code for that endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a 400 because the request you sent isn't what the server is expecting. Find out the object the server is expecting on that endpoint. Then form your request body to match that object.

Comment: This may be a rookie question, but where can I see what exactly is server expecting? I am using IIS Express from Visual studio as a Server

Comment: You are making a POST request to an endpoint "/api/trips/tripname/stops". There is code that defines that endpoint probably C# since you tagged this asp.net-mvc. You can see the object the server expects as a parameter to the method for that route.

Comment: I have also added C# code. Is it now more obvious what might cause the problem?

Comment: The object you post should match the StopViewModel object